# NumberFormat API clarification

Tags: java, text, formatting, number-formatting

Directly from this API:

> NumberFormat helps you to format and parse numbers for any locale.
>   Your code can be completely independent of the locale conventions for
>   decimal points, thousands-separators, or even the particular decimal
>   digits used, or whether the number format is even decimal.

What do they mean with `or even the particular decimal digits used, or whether the number format is even decimal.`?

Answer (score -1):

I could provide one such example - Japanese Yen.
In japanese yen, there is nothing like a 1.2 Yen; it is always a whole number and lowest denomination is 1 yen. So there would never be a decimal place for the currency amount in Yen.

In India the 1 million is displayed as 10,00,000; while the same in US currency is 1,000,000.

Run the below code to see the beauty of locale for a number:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;


// The following example code demonstrates converting a number 
// (double) into a formatted String according to different 
// number formatting standards in various countries

public class FormatDecimalLocalFormat {

public static void main(String[] args) {

// circumference of earth in km
double number = 40075.168776;

// Germany
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
System.out.println(df.format(number));

// United states
df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
System.out.println(df.format(number));

// China
df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.CHINESE);
System.out.println(df.format(number));

// France
df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
System.out.println(df.format(number));

}
}
```

Output confirming to

> Your code can be completely independent of the locale conventions for
>   decimal points, thousands-separators, or even the particular decimal
>   digits used, or whether the number format is even decimal.

```
40.075,169
40,075.169
40,075.169
40 075,169
```

Comment: you have not answered my question

Comment: Then re-format your question please. I guess you have asked, how locale change make code/data independent of representation; and this given working code is the best example for that.

Comment: I can second that: Instead of downvoting the attempts to come closer to an answer spend your time in clarifying the question, which obviously doesn't seem to be as clear as you might assume.

Comment: I clearly specified the bit I was unclear with. And that's what I do not understand. However if you did not get the question. I am referring to the part of the quote I highlighted, which is not what your example shows.

Comment: your example shows: `Your code can be completely independent of the locale conventions for decimal points, thousands-separators,`. I have thoroughly understood this concept which is what you explain in your answer. I would like to know the meaning of the rest of the quote which is `or even the particular decimal digits used, or whether the number format is even decimal.`

Comment: I told you information about Yen, where a particular decimal digit is of no meaning..

Comment: which as of now I have quite figured out.. perhaps they are refering to numericShaper class and getIntegerInstance method of NumberFormat

Comment: Also, could you figure out, if 40 075,169 was actually a decimal number 40075.168776; if you are not told the locale (example of **whether the number format is even decimal**)